# how to send data with header in php to next page

Tags: php

I'm creating a signup function in php. After successful signup I need to display a success message on the login page.

My code for signup message,

```
$message = nl2br('you have sucess fully registered <br/> You Login ID and password detail has been sent<br/>
to your email id'); header("Location:login.php?message=$message");
```

By this I am sending data to next page but I'm not getting there on login page.

Comment: Please can you explain better your question?

Comment: better use session for displaying the message on login page

Comment: Your code (if I can read that correctly..) looks to be correct. How are you reading it in the next page?

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be caused from nl2br function. Try to write this code insead of your:

```
$message = base64_encode('you have sucess fully registered <br/> You Login ID and password detail has been sent to your email id'); 
header("Location: login.php?message=$message");
```

and in the other page do this:

```
$message = nl2br(base64_decode($_GET['message']));
echo $message;
```

NOTE: if you output something before call header the header you want to send to client can't be send!